# Keeping my own additional Python layer information for potential further usage in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I wrote a plugin that selectively loads simulation data to QGIS. That works fine, but the overhead to convert the data from my own format to QGIS takes a long time, as I have to generate an index and hash-tags etc. After finishing my script, the index is lost.

Later, if I want to work with one of my layers, I don't want to do this work again. It would be nice if I could somehow attach the index and hash-tag list to my QGIS layer, to access it with other scripts later. Currently I have to save it on the disc.

Does anybody know where I could smuggle this data in my layers?

Answer (score 1):

You can just store anything as an attribute of the layer object:

```
 pts = canvas.layer(0)
 pts.fnord = {'this': 999}
```

but you risk clashing with something that already exists, and a its a bit... dirty.

Better would be to create a new class as a subclass of Vector or Raster Layer, and define new methods there. That also gives you the option of overwriting the readXml (or readLayerXML) and writeXml methods so that your extra data gets saved with the project. See the API docs for details.

Not sure if there's an example of this technique somewhere in the world of plugins...

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy for the settings to be stored in project files, then use `QgsMapLayer.setCustomProperty(key, value)`. This has the limitation that only when the layer in question is opened as part of that project does it have the custom property. The advantage is that you are not altering the source layer, so you could add such properties to remote read-only layers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pts = canvas.layer(0)
 pts.fnord = {'this': 999}
```

This approach is unfortunately lost when the script is finished.
If you try to read `pts.fnord` with another script later,  this information is not available anymore ... and crashes